# Why doesnt this work? get Use of unassigned local variable 'infos'error "

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
InstaSharp.Model.Responses.MediasResponse test4 = tagsApiAuth.Recent("testph140408");

    List<RecentInfo> infos;  

    foreach (InstaSharp.Model.Media data in test4.Data)  
    {

        var info = new RecentInfo();

        info.Comment = data.Comments.Text;
        info.ImageUrl = data.Images.StandardResolution.Url;

        infos.Add(info);

    }
    return View(infos); 
}

[HttpPost]
//Must i declare here im open for help guys!
public ActionResult TestData(RecentInfo infos)
{
    var info = new RecentInfo();

    info.Comment = infos.Comment;
    info.ImageUrl = infos.ImageUrl;

    return RedirectToAction("TestData");
}
```

Comment: I get that error up top "unassigned"

Comment: Please format your code properly so that we can understand what you've got.

Comment: `RecentInfo` in the `ActionResult` will be a posted variable from the form.

Comment: i dont know what that mean, im pretty new to working with MVC :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you never assign the infos variable!

```
List<RecentInfo> infos;  //This is null!

...
```

Declaring a reference type variable (of which List is) just gives you a name (the reference is *null*). You have to then assign it to an actual object:

```
List<RecentInfo> infos = new List<RecentInfo>();  //This is assigned!

...
```

Comment: Hmm by the moment i just try to get out a tag"name" from my list but do i have to throw in an default value? Because its null and my HttpPost method is not correct i think either.

Comment: In your foreach you perform an `infos.Add()`. Unless the list variable gets assigned to a valid list (however you get it), its going to break. From what I can see all you need to do is give it a new list! This is different than giving it a "default" value. You can't add to a list that isn't there, so if you don't already have one, you need to create a new one.

Comment: thnx for your patience Lord. Im trying to sort on tags, just now im testing to get pitcures hits on the name "testph140408" which is an tag i have created by my self so i should get 1 hit on that name no more than that. But i cant get:/ Do i add that name to new List<RecentInfo>(testph140408); or i guess im totaly lost...:/

Comment: You are going to have to post the query, I don't have enough information to solve that problem :( I'm not sure what any of the classes you are using do or look like. If you post the query I might be able to help.

Comment: namespace tagZ.Models
{
    public class RecentInfo
    {
        public string SearchTag { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: That is the data class, I still need the query. Also, could you add this as an edit to the question? Its very hard to read code in comments.

Comment: I tried to post it but i couldnt.. cant u take my email and just write or something and i mail u the code or u know an other way where i can share my code to u?

Comment: You couldn't edit the post? That's odd. If its a one line query, post in a comment and I'll take a look and edit it for you. If the code is too big, could you post a link to a place I could get the code?

Comment: Perhaps you should post the new code as a new question? By the way, if you have a List<T>, you already have an IEnumerable! Also, when you feel your question is answered remember to "check" the answer you feel was most correct/helpful. It gives you and the answerer some reputation, and lets the community know what helped you the most! If you post the link to the new question I would be happy to take a look!

Comment: just complains on the formating..when i try to post my code.

Comment: Ah, perhaps ask on Meta Stack Overflow, and remove any special characters/formatting from your code. I've personally never run into that error. If you post with no formatting whatsoever I can edit for you.

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=14E6BEECDB0E83BB!107&authkey=!ADAuYjTiJ_bIYaI&ithint=file%2c.docx

Comment: I made an word dokument of codes on 2 views and my homecontroller.

Comment: Thank you for posting the code, could you point out where you are retrieving the pictures matching a specific tag?

Comment: var tagsApiAuth = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Tags.Authenticated(config, authInfo);
        var test1 = tagsApiAuth.GetJson("testph140408");
        var test2 = tagsApiAuth.Get("testph140408");
        var test3 = tagsApiAuth.Search("testph140408");

Comment: im only using one tag for 3 pitcures and i own that instagram account by myself as a testing instagram to get to private users. They accept and then get redirected to my page but i have connected something wrong in my httpPost action so it doesnt compilled. if i dont have anything in httpPost i come to my account and i can se my profile and tag but now i try to" make so the user can search for just that tag in a search bar on my website.

Comment: It sounds like you might just be having trouble with their API. I would ask this as a new question as I haven't ever used it! Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: no worries i think so to but i think i have written wrong in my httpPost im unsure on that part :/

Comment: oh one question do u know why its shows that infos is not declared?

Comment: It looks declared to me :). Did you add the instantiation as in my answer? It isn't done in the code you sent.

Comment: I did test your answer but it didnt compilled. Cant u send a code snip on how u should use my code that u view in that Generic list?

Comment: Ummm... what didn't compile? What was the error? Just setting to a new List shouldn't generate a compiler error.

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[tagZ.Models.RecentInfo]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'tagZ.Models.RecentInfo'.

Comment: That error sounds like it is coming from somewhere else. Check wherever you are doing a dictionary add and see why it is getting a the list.